# Can spring MVC run without an application server?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I was taking a look to Spark Framework and I noted that it does not need an application server to run. Can I configure Spring MVC to run like spark? I am going to implement a restfull service and I am not going to use JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html :

> The Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is designed around a **DispatcherServlet**

Spring MVC is based on the Java `Servlet` specification, you can't run it without using a Servlet container, however you can easily embed one, especially if you use Spring Boot. More details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html